# Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router

I am trying to make a redirect process for Angular. But the algorithm that runs to localhost gives the following error on the real site. How can I fix this error?

> **Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren**

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo:
      navigator.language.slice(0, 2) == 'tr' ||
      'en' ||
      'de' ||
      'kr' ||
      'nl' ||
      'ja' ||
      'it'
        ? navigator.language.slice(0, 2)
        : 'en',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Comment: a dynamic redirectTo is not allowed in AOT mode

Comment: So how can I create this algorithm?